# python deleted from usr/lib/python

Tags: python-2.7

```
$ python
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

Comment: How did you install python?

Comment: Also what does `which python` return?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Python. Open a terminal and run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python
```

This should fix your problem.